# Selecting a DIV using multiple classes in multiple levels

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid list-item-main-euvou-entradas">
    <div class="span1 list-item-main-euvou-entradas-colorcode green"></div>
    <div class="span1 list-item-main-euvou-entradas-rank">1</div>
    <div class="span1 list-item-main-euvou-entradas-votes">Votos</div>
    <div class="span9 list-item-main-euvou-entradas-content">
        <a href="#">some link</a>
        <p>some text...<p>          
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to select this class "span1 list-item-main-euvou-entradas-colorcode green" using also this classes in the selector "row-fluid list-item-main-euvou-entradas".

Ive tried something like this, but does not work:

```css
.row-fluid .list-item-main-euvou-entradas .span1 .list-item-main-euvou-entradas-colorcode .green {
    some css code;
}
```

Any clue on this one?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces between the class:

```
.row-fluid.list-item-main-euvou-entradas .span1.list-item-main-euvou-entradas-colorcode.green {
    some css code;
}
```

so for the parent div (2 classes)

```
.row-fluid.list-item-main-euvou-entradas
```

and the child (3 classes)

```
.span1.list-item-main-euvou-entradas-colorcode.green
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

***CSS CODE***

```
   div.row-fluid.list-item-main-euvou-entradas div.span1.list-item-main-euvou-entradas-colorcode.green {
       /*some css code*/
        color:red;
    }
```